# Describing the Language of a DFA with 7 States

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

So in my attempt to convert the following DFA into a regular expression, I ended up with `((ba)*(ab(ab)*)*(aa(ba)*a)*)*`. The exercise I'm following wants me to convert the DFA into a regular expression then describe its language in plain English, however, I can't seem to come up with anything for the converted expression. Any hints on how to go from here?

[image: DFA in question]

Comment: It's not a simple task. One thing I notice is that you can't have two B's in a row. Anything else? Also, your regular expression seems wrong because aaaba matches the DFA but not the regex

Comment: Yeah, I also noticed the part about no bb's, but I'm not sure about any other pattern. I tried redoing the regex but I'm still quite lost ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accept a string, you must start in $q_0$ and end in $q_0$ or in $q_3$.
A path from $q_0$ to $q_0$ can make a cycle through $q_5$ (so you can have $(ba)^*$) or through $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$ (and so $a(ba)^*a(ba)^*a$), and then you can put these together to obtain $((ba)^*+a(ba)^*a(ba)^*a)^*$.
A path from $q_0$ to $q_3$ is a path from $q_0$ to $q_0$ and then a path that do not pass twice through $q_0$ from $q_0$ to $q_3$, i.e. $ab(ab)^*$.

Now, we can put all together:
$$((ba)^*+a(ba)^*a(ba)^*a)^*(\varepsilon+(ab)^+)$$

A description of this language in plain English could be something like this: strings of the type $((ba)^*+a(ba)^*a(ba)^*a)^*$ or $((ba)^*+a(ba)^*a(ba)^*a)^*(ab)^+$. The first type if formed by strings starting either with $a$ or $b$, with no consecutive $b$s, such that the number $a$s exceeds the number of $b$s by a multiple of 3 (0 included), and ending with $a$; the second type if formed by strings of the first type concatenated with $(ab)^+$, so with a nonempty string starting with $a$, ending with $b$ and such that no two consecutive letters are equal.

Here is the simplest description: strings without consecutive $b$s such that the number $a$s exceeds the number of $b$s by a multiple of 3 (0 included).